# Number of different keyboard layouts?

Tags: combinatorics

Pretty really stupid question probably, but if I would have a keyboard with the 30 main keys (<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>) in how many different keyboard arrangements could I put them provided their possible locations are fixed?

After playing around a bit I would think the answer would be equal to the number of different ways I can arrange 1 to 30, which would be $30!$...? But that answer seems far bigger than I would expect it to be (265252 billion billion billion). Am I doing something wrong or is that really correct?

Comment: You're correct. The number of possible arrangements increases _very_ quickly as the number of keys increases. Try it out with four and then five keys yourself (and six if you feel adventurous).

Comment: So $30!$ is clearly correct, almost the definition of the number of permutations of thirty things.  Are you asking about the numerical value being correct?

Comment: @hardmath If it's correct than so be it. It's been many many years since I did this kind of stuff so I was assuming I was making a very simple conceptual mistake somewhere (I just came up with this answer by noticing 30 nPr 30 equaling 30!...). Either way, thanks for the help, I really needed a sanity check.

Comment: Do you want to include dvorak?